# Remove the selected item from a Kendo UI Multiselect Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I got two Kendo ui multiselect elements on my page to select stores from a list. On the select event I have a function call where I check if the selected store is in another list.

If the selected item is already assigned to the other list i prompt a confirm. When the user click ok, then is ok, when clicks cancel i have to remove the selected item from the multiselect element.

Here is my function:

```
function checkStoreSelection(e) {

    var selectedStore = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
    var selectedStoreId = selectedStore.Id;

    $.each(surveysData, function (index, surveyVal) {
        // get each store
        $.each(surveyVal.Stores, function (storesIndex, storesVal) {
            // check if a store already assigned to another survey
            if (selectedStoreId == storesVal.DBId) {
                var answer = confirm('Some text here ... ');
                if (answer) {
                    // nothing todo here
                } else {
                    // have to remove the selected item
                }
            }

        });
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn fool - Simple answer:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Does what I need :-/
I´am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove item from datasource `dataSource.remove(item);`

Check this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/D4g8S/

Comment: Hey, thanks for that but the datasource element should not be changed, so that the user can select the same as before.